# Can't retrieve value in Redis in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I can store a key/value in Redis but I can't retrieve the value.

store.js

```
var client = redis.createClient();

token ='ghg782Nm';
webhook = 'http://test.com'; 

//store the key/value in Redis   
client.set(token, webhook, function(err, reply) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
});

//get the value 
client.get(token, function(err, value) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  }
console.log(value); //return 'http://test.com'

});
```

I get the right value here but when I want to get it from a different file (somewhere_else.js), the value is null.

somewhere_else.js

```
var client = redis.createClient();

token ='ghg782Nm';

//get the value 
client.get(token, function(err, value) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  }
console.log(value); //Return null

});
```

What did I miss? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try using the same `client` instance between the two files? Perhaps the `set()` hasn't finished before you call `get()` from the other file?

Comment: @mscdex How did I use the same client from the other file?

Comment: Create the client in a separate file, and export it as a module. Then require this file in `store.js` and `somewhere_else.js`, and use it for both the operations. But make sure you're calling `get` only after `set` is finished.

Answer (score 1):

I test your code but everything ok. Run score.js first then run somewhere_else.js.
If you get null may be, get() run before set()

Comment: It's not possible, I run store.js first, get the "ok" reply from redis and then run somewhere_else.js.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the value resides in redis using redis-cli ?
If yes then do

```
Redis.select(0, d function(.......)
```

It will select the database 0 although default is zero but just to be sure if the config is not tampered with.